# Postgres JSON field

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE table_a
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  name json,
  CONSTRAINT table_a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE table_a
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Data in the table:

```
1;"{"ru":"Название","en":"Name"}"
2;"{"ru":"Название","en":"Name"}"
```

When I trying select the name

```
SELECT id, name->'en'::text as name from table_a;
```

have next results:

```
1;""Name""
2;""Name""
```

How I can select data without quotes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `->` operator returns `JSON`. Try using `->>` operator - it returns `varchar`. Something like:

```
SELECT id, name->>'en'::text as name from table_a;
```